# Auth::logout() is working in local but not in server for JWT authentication in Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, lumen, server-error

In my Laravel Lumen (version 8) application, When I'm trying to log out using Auth::logout() 500 server error is occurring. I'm not able to capture the log why this issue is there.

My logout() is defined as below :

```
public function logout()
{
     Auth::logout();

     return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully logged out']);
}
```

[I have found 500 error. The actual error is not showing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSqIT.png)

I have tried to fix with every possible changes. But nothing worked for me.
Kindly help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Note :- 1. I have tried with auth()->logout(). but didn't work.
2. I have also tried with session flush or destory, still didn't work.
3. Also tried with Auth::invalidate, didn't work.

In any of the above changes, 500 server error is there and even the token is not expiring.

Comment: Try debugging the back-end. The 500 indicates an error occurs and guessing what the error would be may not be very efficient. Perhaps your server log-files can help you out too.

Comment: Hi Randy,
In my log file, there is no error log capturing. That's why I'm unable to find the root cause of the issue.

Comment: @Randy Do you have solution for this.

Comment: Try catch the auth logout and log the error.

Comment: Hi @marius-ciclistu
I have tried that too. But still not getting the error in log file.
This behaves so strange. The concern is same code is working in local but not in server.

Comment: Then it is not reaching that code. Search the server logs for that 500 to see what is wrong. Maybe db connection. But you could also try to log the error in the exception handler. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors#the-exception-handler

Comment: My logs folder has not write permission That's why I'm not able to check the error.
Now my issue has fixed. Thanks everyone for your valuable feedback.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My logs folder has not write permission That's why I'm not able to check the error.
Now my issue has fixed.

Thanks everyone for your valuable feedback.